The existence of pure strategy nash equilibrium and best responses
I am studying game theory with Fudenberg and Tirole, and not so familiar with this area of economics.
Suppose there are only two players in a strategic game with complete information. Then, is the statement below correct?
A strategy profile belongs to the intersection of best responses if and only if it is a pure strategy Nash Equilibrium.
Here, best response is defined as below:
A strategy $s_i \in S_i$ is a best response to a given strategy $\mu_{-i} \in \Delta(S_{-i})$ such that
$$u_i(s_i, \mu_i) \geq u_i(s_i', \mu_{-i}) \text{ for all }s_i' \in S_i$$
Also, what would happen if we have more than two players?

Here's a new answer for your updated question.
$\left( \impliedby \right)$ : This direction certainly holds. Suppose $s_1 \in S_1$ and $s_2 \in S_2$ is a pure strategy Nash equilibrium, ie.
$$u_1 \left( s_1, s_2 \right) \geq u_1 \left( \mu_1, s_2 \right) \quad \forall \mu_1 \in \Delta(S_1)$$
$$u_2 \left( s_2, s_1 \right) \geq u_2 \left( \mu_2, s_1 \right) \quad \forall \mu_2 \in \Delta(S_2)$$
In particular, $s_1$ is a (pure) best response to $s_2$ and $s_2$ is a (pure) best response to $s_1$. Therefore, the strategy profile $(s_1, s_2)$ belongs to the intersection of best responses.
$\left( \implies \right)$ : This direction does not hold. Consider the game
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& L & R \\ 
\hline
U & (1, 0) & (0, 1) \\ \hline
D & (0, 1) & (1, 0) \\ \hline
\end{array}
$U$ is a (pure) best response to $L$ and $R$ is a (pure) best response to $U$. Therefore, $(U, R)$ is in the intersection of (pure) best responses, but is not a Nash equilibrium.

Thanks, I think this is the one I needed!

No, the statement is not correct. Consider the matrix game
$$\begin{bmatrix} (1, 1) & (0, 0) \\ (0, 0) & (1, 1) \end{bmatrix}$$
where the row player chooses $U$ or $D$ and the column player chooses $L$ or $R$.
Observe the strategy profile $\frac{1}{2}U + \frac{1}{2}D$ and $\frac{1}{2}L + \frac{1}{2}R$ is a Nash equilibrium, but neither player follows a pure strategy.

I edited my question above. With the "best response" defined as above(defined as a subset of possible pure strategies), is the statement still false?

You're overriding the usual definition of best response and requiring a best response to be a pure strategy?

The set $S_i$ is a set of all pure strategies, so that the best response is confined to some purer strategies. And yes, I wonder if the intersection of best responses is equal to pure strategy Nash equilibria(within this confined definition).
